Firebase auth: issue when logging out user when multiple iOS apps live under the same project
We have 10 fitness apps that use Firebase Auth, RTDB, Crashlytics and other services under one Firebase project. This was done intentionally, because apps are different targets, sharing almost the same code but different content.
Also, we don't want to force users to sign in with firebase from the very beginning, they have an option to start using an app as anonymous users and only then link their uid with Firebase.
Given that user installed 2 apps - FitnessApp1 and FitnessApp2, there could be 2 scenarios
Scenario 1. User signed in FitnessApp1 initially using Apple ID or Email auth, or linked account later, he was issued UID1. User signed in FitnessApp2 using the same credentials - he was given the same UID1 by Firebase. Everything is fine in this scenario.
Scenario 2. User signed in FitnessApp1 initially using Apple ID or Email auth, or linked account later, he was issued UID1. User signed in FitnessApp2 as anonymous, was given UID2 by Firebase. After linking account later with same credentials link goes fine, with no errors. When the user now deletes account in any of the apps, the second one's account becomes invalid and there is no more possibility to log in using provided credentials.
How to handle this situation properly given that we already have >200,000 of users and separation to different projects seems to be impossible yet?
